# Link Parse with android studio for withdraw action between accounts

Tags: android, parsing

I need your kind help regarding link parse (back4app) with android studio project in order to transfer money(balance) between accounts... If there is any method to link table on java class.

knowing that I already linked parse with regstration and login activity.

I itried to use same method when add new user on parse

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.